# What is Angularjs $compile function 2nd and 3rd parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this example

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div compile-template ng-bind-html="post"></div>
</div>
```

And the angularjs code:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $sce,$timeout) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.post = $sce.trustAsHtml("<h1>hello {{name}}</h1>");
    $timeout(function(){
     $scope.name = "3333";
    },3000);
});

angular.module("myApp").directive('compileTemplate', ["$compile", "$parse", function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attr) {
            var parse = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function value() { return (parse($scope) || '').toString(); }

            $scope.$watch(value, function() {
                $compile(element, null,-9999)($scope); 
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

If you look carefully, you will notice this function.

```
$compile(element, null,-9999)($scope);
```

If i make it `$compile(element)($scope)`, it does not work any longer.

Why is that?

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bugd67e3/4/

Answer (score 2):

The third argument of [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) is `maxPriority`. From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage):

> Only apply directives lower than given priority (Only effects the root
>   element(s), not their children)

When you run it like `$compile(element, null,-9999)($scope);`, you are telling compiler to skip all the directives on the `element` with priority greater than `-9999`. That is why `compileTemplate` directive will not be "self-compiled" because the default priority is 0 and [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) will not run twice, since:

> This directive executes at priority level 0.

When removing the third param [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) will be compiled and linked again. The same thing will happen to your `compileTemplate` directive as well. Since you have set up a `$watch`and `$compile` is called inside of it, you will get

`[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

error because of infinite "self-compilation". This is one of so called ["Double Compilation"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#double-compilation-and-how-to-avoid-it) issues.

The second argument is [`transclude` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) (it does not play any role in your case since it is passed as `null`):

> Function available to directives - DEPRECATED.